# SQL query does not give the output when using variables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have inserted below query in a sql table.

```
select account_num,bill_seq,bill_version,
to_char(start_of_bill_dtm,'YYYYMM-DD') st_bill_dtm, 
to_char(bill_dtm - 1,'YYYYMM-DD') en_bill_dtm,
to_char(actual_bill_dtm,'YYYYMM-DD') act_bill_dtm, 
round((invoice_net_mny + invoice_tax_mny)/1000,0) mon_bill,
bill_type_id,bill_status
from billsummary
where to_char(bill_dtm - 1,'YYYYMM') between'||chr(32)||
startMonth ||chr(32)||'and'|| chr(32)||endMonth ||chr(32)||
'and cancellation_dtm is null
```

I tried to execute that query in the below loop.

```
FOR a in 1 .. 17 LOOP 
 dbms_output.put_line(startmonth);
 dbms_output.put_line(endmonth);
 dbms_output.put_line('in the loop');
 sql_query:='select run_sql from table_1';
 Execute IMMEDIATE sql_query;
 Execute IMMEDIATE 'commit';
END LOOP;
```

But it did not give any output. I tried to execute the same query by hard coding 'startMonth' and 'endMonth' as below.

```
select account_num,bill_seq,bill_version,
to_char(start_of_bill_dtm,'YYYYMM-DD') st_bill_dtm, 
to_char(bill_dtm - 1,'YYYYMM-DD') en_bill_dtm,
to_char(actual_bill_dtm,'YYYYMM-DD') act_bill_dtm, 
round((invoice_net_mny + invoice_tax_mny)/1000,0) mon_bill,
bill_type_id,bill_status
from billsummary
where to_char(bill_dtm - 1,'YYYYMM') between'202011 'and'202104'and cancellation_dtm is null
```

Then it worked and gave me an output. Values of the variables(startMonth & endMonth) are also visible in the loop. Does anyone can identify the reason?

**Updated**

I updated the query to use a bind variable as mentioned in the solution.

This is my procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure schema.sixMonthAverage (startMonth varchar,endMonth varchar ,thirdMonth varchar )
IS
start_date varchar :=:startMonth;
end_date varchar :=:endMonth;

begin

for c_rec in(select run_sql from table_1)
 loop
      execute immediate c_rec.run_sql using start_date, end_date;
END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Exception');
END;
/
```

This gives me the error 'bad bind variables' for 'startMonth' and 'endMonth'.

This is how I call the procedure.

```
Execute Schema.sixMonthAverage ('202011', '202104', '202001');
commit;
```

The query is in the table_1. It is shown below.

```
create table tbl_six_mon_1
as
select account_num,bill_seq,bill_version,
to_char(start_of_bill_dtm,'YYYYMM-DD') st_bill_dtm, 
to_char(bill_dtm - 1,'YYYYMM-DD') en_bill_dtm,
to_char(actual_bill_dtm,'YYYYMM-DD') act_bill_dtm, 
round((invoice_net_mny + invoice_tax_mny)/1000,0) mon_bill,
bill_type_id,bill_status
from billsummary
where to_char(bill_dtm - 1,'YYYYMM') between :start_date and :end_date
and cancellation_dtm is null
```

Can anyone identify the error in my approach?

Comment: 1. You execute `select run_sql from table_1`, there's nothing to commit. Try to run it by yourself in the console/IDE. PL/SQL does the same. 2. Your filter predicate contains string `|| chr(32)||endMonth ||chr(32)||` which is not a date and no date will ever be selected with this condition. 3. `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` executes the given statement with its own isolated context, so it doesn't know about any external variables. It is not the execution of the text printed with `dbms_output`. To pass variables, you need to use `using` addition

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but,

problem 1.

I assume you are inserting the first query in table_1 and attempting to execute that query after extracting it from table_1. The quoting looks all wrong.

```
where to_char(bill_dtm - 1,'YYYYMM') between'||chr(32)||
startMonth ||chr(32)||'and'|| chr(32)||endMonth ||chr(32)||
'and cancellation_dtm is null
```

I would expect it to look like

```
where to_char(bill_dtm - 1,'YYYYMM') between startMonth and endMonth
and cancellation_dtm is null
```

problem 2.

I suspect startMonth and endMonth are not in context for the SQL inserted into table_1
Maybe something like (it's been years since I have done this sql, so my syntax may be wrong)

You could use Bind variables and have the assumption that the query in table_1 has 2 bind variables.

```
**your SQL query here.**
where to_char(bill_dtm - 1,'YYYYMM') between :1 and :2
and cancellation_dtm is null
```

and when you execute the statement, establish those bind variables.

```
execute immediate sql_query using startMonth, endMonth,
```

problem 3.

Your final query, you have a trailing space in the hard coded '202011 '

As I said, it's been years since I have done this sort of thing so my syntax may be a little off, but it should point you in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not expect output to be displayed directly in PL/SQL code

```
FOR a in 1 .. 17 LOOP 
 dbms_output.put_line(startmonth);
 dbms_output.put_line(endmonth);
 dbms_output.put_line('in the loop');
 sql_query:='select run_sql from table_1';
 Execute IMMEDIATE sql_query;
 Execute IMMEDIATE 'commit';
END LOOP;
```

Instead of using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`
use select into and store data into a Collection
then display it using DBMS_OUTPUT package.

The second thing you are using Between keyword with char
`where to_char(bill_dtm - 1,'YYYYMM') between'202011 'and'202104'and cancellation_dtm is null`
which invalidates the logic
use date column directly and do not covert.

```
where bill_dtm between to_date(202011, 'yyyymm') and to_date(202104, 'yyyymm')
```